# What else do I need to consider for travel to Bali, Indonesia?

Tags: international-travel, indonesia, guides, bali

I'm planning a mid-year trip to Bali, to escape the cold Winter here in southern Australia. I will be travelling with my partner and our 7 year old daughter.

My friend referred me to [this Bali travel guide](http://www.columbusdirect.com.au/content/the-ultimate-bali-travel-guide/), after seeing it on Facebook. It looks very thorough.

It covers most important items like visa requirements, vaccinations, safety, travel warnings and importantly - top things to do!

One thing I didn't realise, was that if we stay in a private residence, we need to register with the local Rukun Tetangga (RT) Office and police when we arrive.

Does this include private villas?

Thanks,
CJM

Comment: "Is there anything else that I should know" is an extremely broad, open-ended question. Plus, we don't know what you already know, except by reading a very long web page (37 screens of my web browser).

Comment: Villa rental would depend on who you are renting from.  Licensed accommodation providers (hotels, guesthouses, villa rental agencies, etc) provide guest information to police, hence why you don't need to register your presence when staying there.  Renting a villa through something like AirBnB, would likely fall under the register yourself rules, since private property owners are unlikely to be reporting your presence to police.

Answer (score 2):

It is also true for private Vila. Wherever you stay in Indonesia, even just 1 day, you need to register (also true if you are Indonesian).
The man renting the house can do it for you. He just needs your passport info.

All in all, police in Bali is said to be rather lenient. So don't be to scared about paperwork.

Just one important thing: they are known to control the driving licence of any white man riding a motorbike (they would give you a fine, but of course no receipt).
I know you can get a temporary Indonesian licence from your Australian licence, but I have no idea about the procedure.